# Where to put the default coordinates in the azure react map code(Map.js)

Tags: reactjs, azure, maps

As you can see this is my js code and I'm trying locate using react-azure-maps. But locator is shown at cordinate[0,0], but not at the place we ask for like <LocationMarker center= {78.9629, 20.5937}/>, Can someone resolve this.[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSC90.png][1]

```
import React from 'react'
import {AzureMap, AzureMapsProvider, IAzureMapOptions} from 'react-azure-maps'
import {AuthenticationType} from 'azure-maps-control'
import LocationMarker from './LocationMarker'
const option: IAzureMapOptions = {
    authOptions: {
        authType: AuthenticationType.subscriptionKey,
        subscriptionKey: '<key>'
    },
}
const Map = (center,zoom) => {
    return(
        <div style={{height: '1300px'}}>
            <AzureMapsProvider>
                <AzureMap options={option}>
                    <LocationMarker center= {78.9629, 20.5937}/>
                </AzureMap>
                
            </AzureMapsProvider>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Map
```

Please check to image and tell where is the mistake
The output is shown like this
[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq0Cx.png][2]
The locator is at the wrong position